# I want to contain three.js rendered particles into a single div, but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I am trying to contain the particles rendered by three.js to be contained inside a specific div or html element.

Currently it is spanning across the entire dom and not honoring any specific sizes.

Here is an example I found on codepen [https://codepen.io/deathfang/pen/WxNVoq] I'm just unsure how to contain it inside a parent div vs spanning the entire screen.

I simply want to place all the rendered content inside the div of my choosing:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please consider rewording your question so someone coming along in the future can benefit from this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your codepen in a few ways.

**1st** you need to add an actual div to use:

```
<div id="container" style='width: 637px; height: 280px;'></div>
```

**2nd** you need to modify your code to use an existing element vs adding a new one. (this is around line 729)

```
function init() {

    container = document.getElementById('container');
```

**3rd** You need to tell three.js to use the dimensions of your element instead of using the entire screen size. (this is around line 769)

```
renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
```

Looks like you are getting down votes because you poorly worded your question. Next provide more details and show what you tried, and what didn't work. The clearer your question the faster and better the answers. I hope this is what you were looking for.